# Filtering withing include in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a `photo` models and `tags` model in sequelize. Which i display using the following query

```
models.photo
    .findAll({
        limit: 50,
        offset: ctx.offset,
        include :[{
            model: models.tags,
            as: 'tags'
        },{
            model: models.description,
            as: 'desc'
        }]
    })
  .then((photos) => {
    ctx.res.send(photos);
   });
```

My question, how can i filter photos which contain specific tags ? They are associated using

```
models.photo.hasMany(models.tags, {foreignKey: 'photo', sourceKey: 'name'});
```

For example if a user wants to filter **duck** then i should be able to show all photos of ducks and all tags associated with them ?

Answer (score 4):

You can inner join the `photo` and `tags`
then filter the `tags` by your attribute

```
models.photo
    .findAll({
        limit: 50,
        offset: ctx.offset,
        include :[{
            model: models.tags,
            as: 'tags',
            where: {
                tag_name: 'duck'
            },
            required: true
        }]
    })
    .then((photos) => {
        ctx.res.send(photos);
    });
```

Comment: The nested "where" on the include. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use where clause with `Sequelize.literal()`, following example may help you

```
const filterTagName = 'duck';
models.photo
    .findAll({
        where: Sequelize.literal(`tags.name = '${filterTagName}'`), // assuming you have a field name in tags model and model name is tags
        limit: 50,
        offset: ctx.offset,
        include :[{
            model: models.tags,
            as: 'tags'
        },{
            model: models.description,
            as: 'desc'
        }]
    })
  .then((photos) => {
    ctx.res.send(photos);
   });
```

Comment: It's unable to find col `desciption` which in your code would be `name` . is that because of one many relationship ?

Comment: It would be great if you provide photo and tags model and which column would like to use